# Google Spreadsheet, use array formula with filter betwen date

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

Hy everyone, 
I try a simple trick, Use an array formula with a countblank with a filter between date. Without array, its work great, with an array, it goes crazy. why?

I use a spreadsheet to follow the present or absent off people by month. ([exemple sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IRqD4bCAT7uS8b8OBkaefyDpwnxAc0tncWiw--vIaHk/edit?usp=sharing))
I try to like this by line and its work fine:

```
=COUNTBLANK(FILTER(D9:AU9,D8:AU8>=B4,D8:AU8<=B5))
```

When i try to apply this to every line, its goes crazy :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A8:A19<>"",COUNTBLANK(FILTER(D8:AU,D8:AU8>=B4,D8:AU8<=B5)),""))
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C8 try this formula

```
={""; Arrayformula( if(len(A9:A), countif(if((D9:AU="")*(month($D$8:$8)=month($B$3)), row(A9:A)), row(A9:A)),))}
```

and see if that works?